# Is there a way to match with conditions with C# regex flavour

Tags: regex

I have two strings in file, for example

abcd abcdef xxx
abcd abcdef

is there any way to don't match this two strings at all, but match only if both strings would end with xxx

of course with using regex c# flavour

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

```
.*xxx\r\n.*xxx$
```

This looks for two lines that end with xxx and are separated by a \r\n (carriage return, line feed).

Here is a link to a working example:  [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BHC4wE)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "adsfasdf asdfasd\r\nabcd abcdef xxx\r\nabcd abcdef xxx";
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(".*xxx\r\n.*xxx$");

        var matches = regex.Matches(text);
        Console.WriteLine(matches[0].ToString());
    }
}
```